# Import scss variables into typescript in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass

I'm trying to import SASS (scss) variables in to the javascript in typescript Vue 3 project:

```
// @/assets/styles/colors.scss
$white: #fff;
```

```
// @/assets/styles/_exports.scss
@import "./colors.scss";

:export {
  white: $white;
}
```

```js
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import colors from "@/assets/styles/_export.scss";
</script>
```

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "@/assets/styles/colors.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But I'm getting `Cannot find module '@/assets/styles/_export.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.`.

Any ideas pls?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a declaration file named `shims-scss.d.ts` in `src` directory.

```
// shims-scss.d.ts

declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {[className: string]: string};
  export default content;
}
```

It worked for me to import an object from a `scss` file like as `_exports.scss` you wrote.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks. @Michael Bernares